# jQuery - how to cache $.get request

Tags: jquery, templates, caching

How to cache html file forever or while ?version=1... is not added via $.get request?

I'm trying jQuery templating features, and want my templates to be cached all the time, until i'll change them.

I want to avoid unwanted requests to the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the `cache: true` option when performing your [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) request to cache the response in the browser. For more effective caching you could also set the proper [cache HTTP headers](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html) on the server.

Comment: Cache: true is default option. But that's what firebug is showing: Last Fetched Tue Nov 09 2010 16:07:37 GMT+0200 (FLE Standard Time)
Expires Tue Nov 09 2010 16:13:39 GMT+0200 (FLE Standard Time). Could you please tell a bit more about headers? So basically i need to render that html markup via php and set custom header() and when i need to update certain template, i'll just set it to past date?